# Silverstripe 3 - Using remote SMTP

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, silverstripe

The server I am using doesn't have a local mail SMTP set up. Has anyone sent userforms mail using a remote SMTP host?  What would the best way to go about this be?

I tried a few modules but they are a bit outdated.

**[Update]**

I used: [github.com/markguinn/silverstripe-email-helpers](https://github.com/markguinn/silverstripe-email-helpers)

It seems to be a certificate issue. The error I get is

```
[Warning] stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=*.servername.net' did not match expected CN=smtp.gmail.com'
```

Comment: which modul did you try and what issues arose?
http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons?search=smtp

Comment: It seems to be a certificate issue.
The error I get is `[Warning] stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.servername.net' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com'`
The module I used: https://github.com/markguinn/silverstripe-email-helpers

Comment: I've used that module before and it worked like a charm for me. From the warning you are getting, I get the feeling there might be something else going on. The Gmail SMTP server wouldn't be using a certificate from servername.net. Maybe ask the server's sysadmin if they allow usage of a remote SMTP server?